# jQuery highlight differences in tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, compare

I am trying to compare two HTML tables similar to what has been done here in concept: 
[compare two html tables data line by line and highlight using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548431/compare-two-html-tables-data-line-by-line-and-highlight-using-jquery)

EXCEPT I just need to know if there is any data in either that does not occur in both.

My solution so far has been to go through the first table and if I find a match in the second, highlight it.  If there isn't a match, highlight it in the first table.  (Using found and not found Classes).

This is my code.  The selectors are working but the classes don't seem to stick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#oldScript tr").each(function(){
        $('#newScript tr:contains('+ "" + this.innerHTML + "" + ')').addClass("found");
        if($('#newScript tr:contains('+ "" + this.innerHTML + "" + ')').length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("notFound");
            alert("Row not found \n" + $(this).innerHTML);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean, don't seem to stick?

Comment: When I test in Firefox and use Firebug, there was a time when I would see the class appear on the td element, but the change wouldn't occur.  Now I'm not even seeing that.

Comment: Is this a scope issue?  Do I not have access to the real table from within the each function?

Comment: oldScript and newScript are my tables

Answer (score 1):

When you use `each` it is best to use the parameters in the callback function as defined in the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). It would be helpful to have a fiddle but try something like this instead of using `this` inside the loop (notice the parameters to the callback function now).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#oldScript tr").each(function(index, item) {
        $('#newScript tr:contains('+ "" + item.innerHTML + "" + ')').addClass("found");
        if($('#newScript tr:contains('+ "" + item.innerHTML + "" + ')').length == 0){
            $(item).addClass("notFound");
            alert("Row not found \n" + item.innerHTML);
        }
    });
});
```